# How can an instruction be fetched every cycle?

Tags: cpu, duty-cycle, cache, instruction-set

From what I understand, in a pipelined CPU, every stage takes 1 cycle. But instructions are fetched from memory which takes up to ~150 cycles. The CPU fetches most instructions from the L1-cache, but I've read that it takes around 4 cycles. From that logic, a new instruction should only start every 4th cycle, which obviously makes no sense?
[image]
This diagram shows a new instruction starts every cycle.

So, how does the CPU fetch a new instruction every cycle, if it takes more than one cycle to even fetch an instruction?

Comment: There are different "cycles". There are many different clocks in the CPU, and the "main" CPU clock or the memory clock is not necessarily the same as instruction clock.

Comment: Instructions are cached and prefetched.

Comment: More than 1 instruction will typically be fetched from L1 at a time.  On a lot of systems, probably the whole 32 or 64 byte L1 cacheline is loaded, so you'll get 8 or 16 instructions fetched at a time, which is easily enough to hide a 4 cycle latency.

Comment: @user1850479 Okay, I see. But only one instruction can be in the instruction register, right? Where is the rest of the loaded cacheline then stored? In some buffer with a single cycle access time?

Comment: Where did you see L1 fetch takes 4 CPU cycles?

Comment: How many instruction registers you have and where data is copied between the L1 and instruction decoder is an implementation detail that varies widely between processors.  You'd have to specify a specific CPU to get a specific answer.  In general though you can probably think of most modern CPUs as effectively holding many instructions (perhaps dozens or hundreds) in the instruction register concurrently (especially for faster CPUs).

Comment: @jay When I was working on the P2 chipset at Intel, the L1 cache was 3 clocks away from the CPU. The L2 cache was yet another 3 away (so 6 to get to the L2.) But with faster CPUs, I don't doubt 4 cycles for the L1 or even more, perhaps. I've also noticed the L1 cache has been getting smaller over time. And they've added an L3 that didn't exist when I was around at Intel. Doesn't surprise me, if this is about the Intel chips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fetches the next instruction, so they are processed in parallel. Note that next instruction could also fetch the result of the instruction that isn't finished yet. Of course, this is unwanted feature, but it can be triggered by writing the assembler code by hand. The compiler has to keep track on how these instructions are processed and to use the result only after write output (WO).